# I am doing codewars and i am stuck on the students final grade challenge

Tags: javascript

I am not sure what i am doing wrong, it all works but something is off and i cant catch it since i am a newbie, any ideas?

```js
function finalGrade(exam, projects) {
  if (exam >= 90 || projects > 10) {
    return 100;
  } else if (exam >= 75 && projects === 5) {
    return 90;
  } else if (exam >= 50 && projects === 2) {
    return 75;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Question - This function should take two arguments: exam - grade for exam (from 0 to 100); projects - number of completed projects (from 0 and above);

This function should return a number (final grade). There are four types of final grades:

100, if a grade for the exam is more than 90 or if a number of completed projects more than 10.
90, if a grade for the exam is more than 75 and if a number of completed projects is minimum 5.
75, if a grade for the exam is more than 50 and if a number of completed projects is minimum 2.
0, in other cases

Comment: HINT: Read the description carefully. Focus on the logical parts like _is more than_ and _is minimum_. Then compare that to the code you've provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `===` in last to `if` statements. You should use `>=` if you want to check minimum number of projects

```
function finalGrade(exam, projects) {
  if (exam > 90 && projects >= 10) {
    return 100;
  } else if (exam > 75 && projects >= 5) {
    return 90;
  } else if (exam > 50 && projects >= 2) {
    return 75;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you're just going to give the solution? Besides, this isn't correct anyway!

Comment: @RandyCasburn Please don't only tell the solution is wrong. Also tell the reason. Thanks.

Comment: This is a code challenge for the OP. I don't want to _tell the answer_ directly because I'm assuming the OP wants to be successful with the challenge. I won't tell you what's wrong until the OP says "give me the answer please".

Comment: there should be an OR operator inside the first if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just only one part, the structure

```
if () {
    return
} else if () {
    return
} else {
    return
}
```

can be simplified to omit else parts and just go on with `if`

```
if () {
    return
} 
if () {    // as many more
    return
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the all if condition the grade for exam is more than 90, 75, and 50, so it will be just `grade>90`, `grade>75` and `grade>50` and not `grade>=90`, `grade>=75` and `grade>=50`. And another thing is that you should use `>=` instead of `===` .

**Here's my solution:-**

```
  function finalGrade (exam, projects) {

  if(exam > 90 || projects > 10) 
  return 100;
  if(exam > 75 & projects >= 5) 
  return 90;
  if(exam > 50 & projects >= 2)
  return 75;
  return 0;
}
```